# T-SQL Selecting best selling item per state

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have multiple items being sold and shipped throughout the country.  How would I see what the best selling item per state is?

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
CustomerID Int Not 
, Name Varchar(75) 
, UserName Varchar(75) 
, Password Varchar(75) 
, Email Varchar(75) 
, PrimaryPhone Varchar(50) 
, Primary Key (CustomerID)
)

CREATE TABLE ShippingAddress (
AddressID Int Primary Key
, CustomerID Int 
, Street (75) 
, State Varchar (75)
, Zip Varchar (75) 
,Foreign Key (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customers
)

CREATE TABLE PaymentInfo (
CreditCardNumber Int Primary Key 
, CardExpDate Date 
, CVVCode Int 
, CustomerID Int 
, AddressID Int 
, Foreign Key (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customers
, Foreign Key (AddressID) REFERENCES Addresses
)

CREATE TABLE Orders (
OrderID Int Primary Key
, OrderDate Date 
, CustomerID Int 
, TotalPrice Int 
, Foreign Key (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customers
)

CREATE TABLE Shipping (
ShippingID Int Primary Key 
, OrderID Int 
, AddressID Int 
, Foreign Key (OrderID) REFERENCES Orders
, Foreign Key (AddressID) REFERENCES Addresses
)

CREATE TABLE OrderPayment (
OrderID Int 
, CreditCardNumber Int 
, Primary Key (OrderID, CreditCardNumber)
, Foreign Key (OrderID) REFERENCES Orders 
, Foreign Key (CreditCardNumber) REFERENCES PaymentInfo
)

CREATE TABLE Inventory (
ItemModelNumber Int Primary Key 
, Brand Int 
, ItemDescription Text
, StockQuantity Int 
)

CREATE TABLE OrderItems (
OrderID Int 
, ItemModelNumber Int 
, Primary Key (OrderID, ItemModelNumber)
, Foreign Key (OrderID) REFERENCES Orders
, Foreign Key (ItemModelNumber) REFERENCES Inventory
)


CREATE TABLE Sources (
DistributorID Int Primary Key 
, DistributorName Varchar(75) 
)

CREATE TABLE InventorySource (
ItemModelNumber Int 
, DistributorID Int 
, RequestedDate Date 
, DeliveredDate Date 
, RequestedQuantity Int 
, Primary key (ItemModelNumber, DistributorID)
, Foreign Key (ItemModelNumber) REFERENCES Inventory
, Foreign Key (DistributorID) REFERENCES Sources 
)

GO


CREATE VIEW BestSellers AS(
```

So I know I want to SELECT DISTINCT State from ShippingAddress.  Then I think I want count(ItemModelNumber), OrderID from OrderItems table and join those columns with my Distinct State column from the ShippingAddress table.  Then just a GROUP BY statement on State.. Is this correct so far?

Comment: logic is correct but where is query defining your logic ?

Comment: Are all these tables relevant to your query? If not then don't display them as it just adds noise around the question you're asking.

Comment: Seems to me there might be something missing here. Where do I see how many items have been ordered with each order and what the price is. Furthermore, I am a bit hazy what you mean by "best selling". Is it the item which has created the most revenue, the item which was ordered the most, or the item which was shipped the most?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following query provide the best item per state

Note: I am using COUNT(*) because I did not find a "quantity" field for orders

```
SELECT best.*
FROM   (
       SELECT sales.*
            , I.ItemDescription
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PATITION BY sales.State ORDER BY sales.quantity DESC) AS sort
       FROM   (
               SELECT SA.State
                    , OI.ItemModelNumber
                    , COUNT(*) AS quantity
               FROM   OrderItems OI
                   INNER JOIN
                      Shipping   S
                      ON OI.OrderID = S.OrderID
                   INNER JOIN
                      ShippingAddress SA
                      ON S.AddressID = SA.AddressID
               GROUP BY SA.State
                    , OI.ItemModelNumber
               ) sales
           INNER JOIN
               Inventory I
               ON sales.ItemModelNumber = I.Inventory
       ) best
WHERE  best.sort = 1
```

I hope this helps

Regards